# filter function in dplyr 0 Obs

Tags: r, filter

I'm trying to filter a really large data base, but unfortunately every time that I try to use "filter" with more then one label I get 0 obs on the environment.
The filter is (the levels and labels are ready):

```
GrupoHijos <-
      filter(
        casen,
        pco1 == "Hijo(a) de ambos" &
          pco1 == "Hijo(a) sólo del jefe(a)" &
          pco1 == "Hijo(a) sólo del esposo(a)/pareja"
      )
```

Grupo Hijos is the data that I want to make, and casen is my original data base.
The labels I'm trying to filter are "Hijo(a) de ambos", "Hijo(a) sólo del jefe(a)", "Hijo(a) sólo del esposo(a)/pareja".
(Sorry for the bad english)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You can provide a sample of your data using `dput()`. Usually, it is sufficient to figure out the issue with just a small sample using `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: please provide a little reproducible example. You can use `dput` function for this. See [https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput). Having a reproducible example makes it easier to understand the problem and see potential syntax errors. From your description I would ask, whether you are sure, that there are observations, which fulfil the given conditions in `filter` function?

Comment: Im totally sure that the original data base has 216.439 observations, i can give you a better example:

Comment: casen$pco1 <- factor(casen$pco1,
                                     levels = c(1, 4, 5, 6),
                                     labels = c("Jefe(a) de hogar", "Hijo(a) de ambos", "Hijo(a) sólo del jefe(a)", "Hijo(a) sólo del esposo(a)/pareja"))
levels(casen$pco1)

Sujetos <- mutate (casen, pco1 = case_when (pco1 == 1 ~ 1,
                                            pco1 == 4 ~ 2,
                                            pco1 == 5 ~ 2,
                                            pco1 == 6 ~ 2))
At that point i dont get any error and the observations are correct

Comment: The problem is when i try to filter 3 labels together
GrupoHijos <- filter(casen, pco1 == "Hijo(a) de ambos" & pco1 == "Hijo(a) sólo del jefe(a)" & pco1 == "Hijo(a) sólo del esposo(a)/pareja")
Everytime i make this i get 0 obs.
Sorry but i could understand the command dput

Comment: The variable `pco1` is converted as a factor. Did you try to use the corresponding factor levels for filtering instead of the labels, for example `filter(casen, pco1 == 1)` ?

Comment: You can use dput to write a file in ASCII text, which corresponds to your data. Try to use it as following to save the ASCII text on your desktop: `dput(x = casen, file = "path_to_your_desktop/my_data") `. After doing that, you can open the file from your desktop in a simple editor and copy/paste it in your question here.